# Convert HEX string to it's actual string value in c#

Tags: c#, string, encoding, hex, esri

There is a 3rd party code, which returns me the string "Nmimtech1" in form of a byte[] array.

```
    object password1 = pProps.GetProperty("PASSWORD");
```

(Its third party ESRI library code, so do not bother)
Now i convert it to byte[]

```
    byte[] pswrdbyte = password1 as byte[]
```

The content of this byte array are

```
        [0] 2   byte
    [1] 0   byte
    [2] 0   byte
    [3] 0   byte
    [4] 20  byte
    [5] 0   byte
    [6] 0   byte
    [7] 0   byte
    [8] 200 byte
    [9] 115 byte
    [10]    39  byte
    [11]    180 byte
    [12]    150 byte
    [13]    100 byte
    [14]    74  byte
    [15]    44  byte
    [16]    7   byte
    [17]    215 byte
    [18]    137 byte
    [19]    50  byte
    [20]    212 byte
    [21]    138 byte
    [22]    56  byte
    [23]    241 byte
    [24]    134 byte
    [25]    51  byte
    [26]    75  byte
    [27]    0   byte
```

Now i have tried each and every way to convert it back to "Nmimtech1

```
    string str = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "\0\0\0\0\0\0?s'??dJ,\a??2??8??3K\0"

```
    string str1 = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "\0\0珈됧撖ⱊ휇㊉諔㎆K"

```
    string str2 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "\0\0\0\0\0\0�s'��dJ,\a׉2Ԋ8�3K\0"

```
    string str3 =  System.Text.Encoding.UTF32.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "�����"

```
    string str4 = System.Text.Encoding.UTF7.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "\0\0\0\0\0\0Ès'´dJ,\a×2Ô8ñ3K\0"

```
    string str5 = System.Text.Encoding.BigEndianUnicode.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "Ȁ\0᐀\0졳➴除䨬ߗ褲풊㣱蘳䬀"

```
    string str6 = pswrdbyte.ToString();
```

returns "System.Byte[]" (weird)

```
    string s  = BitConverter.ToString(pswrdbyte);
```

returns "02-00-00-00-14-00-00-00-C8-73-27-B4-96-64-4A-2C-07-D7-89-32-D4-8A-38-F1-86-33-4B-00". Now this makes a little sense, but can you tell me how to convert this hex string back to "Nmimtech1" programmatically?

Comment: object password1 is a string containing `Nmimtech1`?

Comment: The byte array you have does not look like a direct representation of Nmimtech1. Therefore I don't think you can do what you're trying to do.

Comment: It isn't necessarily a hexadecimal output. `BitConverter` has literally just converted your `byte[]` from a 8-bit representation to a hexadecimal is all.

Comment: The trick here is to look for patterns in your byte output if there is no documentation available. With only one input this is difficult. The pattern I've noticed is that your input is 9 characters long resulting in a 28 byte long output. 9 * 3 = 27 (+1 byte header). That might be where your string is, who knows. Looking at the bytes I would say the first 10 are some sort of header, leaving the last 18 for your content. Try parsing from location [9] onwards with a UTF-8 (or other 8-bit long) representation

Comment: @AdamKewley i had the same idea, Nmimtech1 contains also 2 'm' but there are no 2 subpatterns in the bytelist as far as i can see

Comment: Your array represents a password and is 224 bits long. Is it possible it's encrypted? 224 bits sounds like a plausible block size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, The password returned from Thirdparty code is encrypted, and i figured out we cant decrypt it. Rather, to store it locally, i will need to store the encrypted form.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

if your 3rd party code returns your string in form of a byte array, why you convert it to a byte array again?

> Now i convert it to byte[]: byte[] pswrdbyte = password1 as byte[]

?

```
        String password1 = "Nmimtech1";
        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

        byte[] pswrdbyte = enc.GetBytes(password1);
```

[image]

```
        string password2 = enc.GetString(pswrdbyte);
```

password2 contains "Nmimtech1" again.

Comment: OP doesn't have the password in a string. He has it in a `byte[]` that he got from a third party library .

Comment: in the picture you see "Nmimtech1" as byte array, i dont know why he wants to convert password1 into a byte array cause he said that it already is one representing "Nmimtech1"

Comment: The line: `object password1 = pProps.GetProperty("PASSWORD");` is where I assume the 3rd party software comes into play.

Comment: @AdamKewley is right. I do not want to convert it back to byte[] . I want to retrieve "Nmimtech1" again

Comment: so he assumes that password1 is a byte array which "should" contain "Nmimtech1"?

Comment: A quick breakpoint analysis may indicate what type `password1` is.

Comment: It it wasn't a byte array, the `as` conversion would return null. It's a byte array.